# How to split a long data frame into lists of data & metadata

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

I am relative newbie to R and have trouble wrapping my head around this fairly basic question. I really appreciate your help with this.

Here're some toy data that look like my actual data:

```
interval = rep(1:5,5)
value = runif(25)
category = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 15))
data = data.frame(category, interval, value)
```

The data will have three columns: a factor column with a categorical variable, a column called "interval" encoding time, and "value" containing the dependent variable. These all express the properties of each observation, which belongs to a "category" and vary in "value" through time ("interval").

```
category | interval | value;
A          1          1.0
A          2          2.3 
A          3          0.5
A          4          0.9
B          1          1.5
B          2          1.2
B          3          0.4
...
```

Now, I want to extract each observation into a txt file with two columns

```
interval | file.number
1          1.0
2          2.3
3          0.5
...
```

and in a separate txt file encodes the metadata

```
category | file.number
A          1
A          2
A          3
B          4 
B          5
B          6
...
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: `L = list(data[,2:3], data[,1:2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a chance for you to try out `mapply`:

```
df <- read.table(text ="category  interval  value
A          1          1.0
A          2          2.3 
A          3          0.5
A          4          0.9
B          1          1.5
B          2          1.2
B          3          0.4", header = T)

l <- split(df, df$interval)

#' Function writes interval data to csv
#' 
#' @return metadata about written records
writeIntervalData <- function(df, i) {
  write.csv(df, paste0("file", i, ".csv", row.names <- FALSE))
  meta <- data.frame(category = unique(df$category))
  meta$file <- i               
  return(meta)
}

meta <- mapply(writeIntervalData, l, names(l), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

meta <- do.call("rbind", meta)
write.csv(meta[order(meta$category, meta$file),], "meta.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```